# how can i use different colors to plot trips

Tags: python, random, geolocation, folium

I want to plot different trips in a map and i want for each trip to be ploted in a different color , so I'm using this code :

```
import random
def triptracer(df):
    df=df.reset_index()
    color1 = ["#"+''.join([random.choice('0123456789ABCDEF') for j in range(6)])]
    this_map = folium.Map(prefer_canvas=True)
    for i in range(df.shape[0]-1):
        if((df['tripId'][i] == df['tripId'][i+1]) ):
            folium.CircleMarker(location=[df['latitude'][i],df['longitude'][i]],color = color1 ,radius=2,weight=2).add_to(this_map) 
        else : 
            color1 = ["#"+''.join([random.choice('0123456789ABCDEF') for j in range(6)])]
    this_map.fit_bounds(this_map.get_bounds())
    return this_map
```

in my case, the data frame contains 58 different trips but the output looks like there are only 8 trips [output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTHTe.png)

does anyone know what is the problem in my code?

the data frame looks like the following

```
tripId     longitude    latitude
1869715     9.961366    48.425659
1869715     9.961353    48.425614
1869715     9.961239    48.425626
1869715     9.961211    48.425686
1869715     9.960998    48.425712
...     ...     ...     ...
1862514     9.939702    48.416177
1862514     9.939587    48.416041
1862514     9.939507    48.415924
1862514     9.939213    48.415989
1862514     9.938921    48.415984
```

Answer (score 0):

final update without more data

```py
import random
import folium
import pandas as pd

# generate distinct color list
def generate_colors(n): 
  hex_values = [] 
  r = int(random.random() * 256) 
  g = int(random.random() * 256) 
  b = int(random.random() * 256) 
  step = 256 / n 
  for _ in range(n): 
    r += step 
    g += step 
    b += step 
    r = int(r) % 256 
    g = int(g) % 256 
    b = int(b) % 256 
    r_hex = hex(r)[2:] 
    g_hex = hex(g)[2:] 
    b_hex = hex(b)[2:] 
    hex_values.append('#' + r_hex + g_hex + b_hex) 
  return hex_values 

# above could be done in much nicer way, will rework

def triptracer(df):
    # amount of colors is amount of unique trip ids in df
    colors = generate_colors(df.tripId.unique().size)

    # map colors to each unique tripID
    colorTable = {}
    for tripID in df.tripId.unique():
        colorTable[tripID] = colors.pop()
    
    df=df.reset_index()
    this_map = folium.Map(prefer_canvas=True)
    
    #group by tripId to get distinct trips and plot them 
    for tripId, grouped_df in df.groupby('tripId'):
        for i, row in grouped_df.iterrows():
            folium.CircleMarker(location=[row['latitude'],row['longitude']],color = colorTable[tripId] ,radius=2,weight=2).add_to(this_map)

    return this_map


df = pd.read_csv('tmp.csv')
print(df)
map = triptracer(df)
map.save('map.html')
```

csv.tmp:

```
tripId,longitude,latitude
1869715,9.961366,48.425659
1869715,9.961353,48.425614
1869715,9.961239,48.425626
1869715,9.961211,48.425686
1869715,9.960998,48.425712
1862514,9.939702,48.416177
1862514,9.939587,48.416041
1862514,9.939507,48.415924
1862514,9.939213,48.415989
1862514,9.938921,48.415984
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it gives the same output, only 6 colors :/